# solana-test-validator: No such file or directory panic

Tags: solana

I am trying to run Solana rust hello world example locally (https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld). I went through the readme but the step "Start local Solana cluster" (https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld#start-local-solana-cluster) is not working for me. I am receiving `thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', validator/src/bin/solana-test-validator.rs:294:71` error.

My solana-test-validator version is 1.7.9

This is my `config.yml` file:

```
Config File: /home/work/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899 
WebSocket URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/work/.config/solana/id.json 
Commitment: confirmed
```

Do you have any idea whats wrong? Or what should I fix / check?

Comment: I also run this `solana-keygen new` but its still the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it with installing a stable version like this: `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"`

Comment: I ran this command, but instead of adding the path, just took the missing binary `solana-test-validator` and moved it to `/us/local/bin`. I then deleted all the files added by this command. It seems to work fine on my Mac with Solana installed via brew.

Answer (score 0):

try cd into validator folder inside solana directory
and then run ./solana-test-validator